Converse of the Lagrange Multipliers Theorem
It's classical the following result:
Theorem (Lagrange multipliers): Let $ U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m $ be an open set, $ f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ a differentiable function, and $ M \subset U $ a level set of a $ C^1 $-submersion $ g = (g_1, \ldots, g_m): U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m $. Then, if $ p \in M $ is a local extremum of $ f |_M $, there exist $ \lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_m \in \mathbb{R} $ such that
$$
\nabla f(p) = \lambda_1 \nabla g_1(p) + \cdots + \lambda_m \nabla g_m(p)
$$
Question: Is the converse of this theorem true? That is, if there exist $ \lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_m \in \mathbb{R} $ such that
$$
\nabla f(p) = \lambda_1 \nabla g_1(p) + \cdots + \lambda_m \nabla g_m(p)
$$
can we conclude that $ p \in M $ is a local extremum of $ f |_M $?
I ask this because, in applications, we use the converse of this result to find candidates for local extrema. Therefore, it would be interesting if the converse were true.

No, the converse does not apply

The bordered Hessian matrix gives you a condition that, in some cases, allows you to deduce that a given critical point (i.e. a give $p$ such that your condition holds) is either a local minimum or local maximum

I can’t remember the canonical counterexample at the moment, but the conditions in the theorem you state are often called the “first order necessary conditions” for this reason

@BenGrossmann Do you know some counterexample?

Here's a counterexample. Consider the functions $f,g:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ given by
$$
f(x,y) = y, \quad g(x,y) = y - x^3.
$$
Let $M = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : g(x,y) = 0\}$. The point $p = (0,0)$ satisfies the given condition with $\nabla f = \nabla g = (1,0)$, but the point $p$ is not a local extremum.
You might notice a correspondence between this example and the fact that the function $h(x) = x^3$ has a critical point but not a local extremum at $x = 0$.
As a general point regarding Lagrange multipliers, you might find it helpful to note that unconstrained optimization problems can always be framed as constrained optimization problems in a similar fashion: instead of optimizing a function, you can say that you're optimizing the dependent variable over the graph of that function. In a sense, this tells you that for everything that can "go wrong" in unconstrained optimization, there is a corresponding problem that arises in the context of constrained optimization.
